# Batch script to find last word in specific line

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I have a text file which contains 2 lines of a sentence. At the end of the 2nd line I have one word say *Alive*. It can be Alive or Down.

Now I have to write one IF statement such that if that text file contains Alive it should print *Hi* else it should print *Hello*. This needs to be done using batch file.

Comment: Read below post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130116/windows-batch-commands-to-read-first-line-from-text-file.  You will have to make it work for you

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
findstr /N . input.txt | findstr /I ^2.*alive$ > NUL    
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (Echo Hi) ELSE (Echo Hello)
pause
```

This batch reads in your text file with the `/N` switch, wich puts a number in front of every line, like:

```
1:This is a test,
2:and I am alive
3:Not?
```

The new text is piped to the second *findstr*, which uses the RegEx pattern `^2.*alive$` to find a line which begins with `2` and ends with `alive`.  That was the hard part.

Since *findstr* sets its errorlevel to 0 if at least one match is found, we can use a simple IF statement to echo "Hi" or "Hello".

---

Batch in detail

- `findstr` searches for [strings in files](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- `/N` puts a line number in front of every line
- `.` is a wildcard for any single character. It tells *findstr* to search for everything
- `|` is the pipe command. The output from the first command is passed as input for the second one
- `/I` tells *findstr* to search case-insensitive so "Alive" and "alive" are both found
- `^` is a RegEx term and stands for a line beginning
- `.*` is a RegEx term and stands for an indefinite number of character
- `$` is a RegEx term and stands for a line ending
- `> NUL` hides the *findstr* output so the matching line isn't displayed in the CMD window
- `IF condition (command) ELSE (command)` is a simple [IF condition](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- `%ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0` is the [exit code](http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) of findstr. "EQU" stands for "equel"

---

**Edit** ([example](http://notepad.cc/share/nR41o7Ikux) taken from OP' comment below)

[image]

1. Your "Alive" isn't at the 2nd line. Its the 5th
2. After "Alive" are three spaces in your example so `alive$`doesn't match

   Change `^2.*alive$` to `5.*alive`. Or even better `^5.* Alive   $`
   Note the spaces.

Comment: Hi,I have tried above command but errorlevel is coming as 1. so it is always fetching Hello.

Comment: Hi,I have tried above command but errorlevel is coming as 1. so it is always fetching Hello.Text file will look like below oabcdefghijklmnop1        | Oabcdefghijklmno2~ |    8496 | Alive   
coreapplication_obijh1           | Oabcdefghijklmno3~ |    8400 | Alive              
cabcdefghijklmnop2             | Oabcdefghijklmno4~ |    9092 | Alive   
coreapplication_obis1            | Oabcdefghijklmno5~ |   10268 | Alive

Comment: Paste your logfile at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or [notepad.cc](http://notepad.cc) and post a link here. I guess your search word "Alive" isn't at the very end of the 2nd line

Comment: Processes in Instance: instance2
---------------------------------+--------------------+---------+---------
ias-component                    | process-type       |     pid | status  
---------------------------------+--------------------+---------+---------
coreapplication_obijh1           | OracleBIJavaHostC~ |    8400 | Alive

Comment: above one is my file, I have to check Alive or down, currently it is showing Alive.

Comment: http://notepad.cc/share/nR41o7Ikux

Comment: @user284262 See the edit